what mistake am I doing here
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(CA_Product_Group__c,'Provider'),
    "Provider",
    IF(
       NOT(
         OR(
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "DRG Customer Service",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "LS/SAR Technical Support Training - EMEA",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "LS/SAR Technical Support Training - AM",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - Japan",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - China",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - Korea",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - SEAP",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - ANZ"        
         ) 
       ),
       "Transfer Case",
       IF ( 
           AND (
               VALUE(TEXT(MID(TEXT(DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) - TIMEVALUE('4:00:00'))),12,2)) >= 20,
                OR (
                    TEXT(DATEVALUE( CA_Created_Date__c  - TIMEVALUE('4:00:00'))) = 
                    TEXT(DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - MOD( 
                    DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - TIMEVALUE('4:00:00')) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ))),
                    TEXT(DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - TIMEVALUE('4:00:00'))) = TEXT(DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c 
                    - MOD( DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - TIMEVALUE('4:00:00')) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 )) + 1)
                )
           ),
           "Out of Coverage",
           "Not Applicable"
       )  
    )  
)


Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Time


You can't subtract a time from a date or date/time. Instead, you can subtract a number, which is in number of days, so want to divide by 24 to represent the number of hours to offset by.
CA_Created_Date__c-(4/24)


You have used the subtraction operator (-) incorrectly in your formula. you cannot directly subtract a Time value from a Date or DateTime value.
The subtraction operator expects both operands to be of the same type: either both Number, both Date, or both DateTime.
This part of the formula causes the error:
VALUE(TEXT(MID(TEXT(DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) - TIMEVALUE('4:00:00'))),12,2)) >= 20

You need to fix this by subtracting DateTime from DateTime or Date from Date.
To subtract 4 hours, you would subtract 4/24 (since there are 24 hours in a day):
DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) - (4/24)

Your formula looks like this:
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(CA_Product_Group__c,"Provider"),
    "Provider",
    IF(
       NOT(
         OR(
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "DRG Customer Service",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "LS/SAR Technical Support Training - EMEA",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "LS/SAR Technical Support Training - AM",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - Japan",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - China",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - Korea",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - SEAP",
           CA_Case_Owner_Name__c  = "Technical Support - ANZ"        
         ) 
       ),
       "Transfer Case",
       IF ( 
           AND (
                VALUE(MID(TEXT(CreatedDate - (4/24)), 12, 2)) >= 20,
                OR (
                    TEXT(DATEVALUE( CA_Created_Date__c  - (4/24))) = 
                    TEXT(DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - MOD( 
                    DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - (4/24)) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ))),
                    TEXT(DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - (4/24))) = TEXT(DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c 
                    - MOD( DATEVALUE(CA_Created_Date__c - (4/24)) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 )) + 1)
                )
           ),
           "Out of Coverage",
           "Not Applicable"
       )  
    )  
)


Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text, I am getting this error

Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text , I am getting this error

can you help me with the answer for this

@Sadiksha, I have updated the formula please check.
